# Binding data from textbox to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm making a Contact info program, where users can enter there name, age and birthday and some other things into textboxes. When you click ok, I want the data to be put into the `DataGrid`.

First I have my `MainWindow`, which opens a new window called `CreateContact` when you press the Create new contact button:

```
CreateContact cc = new CreateContact();
cc.ShowDialog();
```

then a new window open, where you type your name and age and choose the birthdate. Then you click OK:

```
private void cmdOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
     m.name = txtName.Text;
     m.age = txtAge.Text;
     m.birthDate = dpBirthdate.Text;
     m.ShowContacts()
}
```

which should run my method `ShowContacts` in my `MainWindow`:

```
public string name;
public string age;
public string birthDate;

public void ShowContacts()
{
    try
    {
         dgContacts.ItemsSource = LoadContactData();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("" + e);
    }
}

private List<ContactData> LoadContactData()
{
    List<ContactData> list = new List<ContactData>();
    list.Add(new ContactData()
    {
        Name = name,
        Age = age,
        BirthDate = birthDate
    });            
    return list;
}


public class ContactData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

But nothing happens, I get no data in the `DataGrid`. I hope someone can tell me what is wrong. I have really tried searching a lot on what is causing the `DataGrid` to show no data.

Comment: I can't understand when are you persisting the contact information and how are you retrieving it?

Comment: pls explain how are you retrieving datat ?

Comment: Please post your XAML code

Comment: 1) name, age, and birthDate need to be setup as properties. 2) Use INPC and ObservableCollections instead of rebuilding the ItemsSource every time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `dgContacts` is the datagrid view control, you have to call the following command to ensure that the data is bound

> dgContacts.DataBind();

The procedure is similar to the one that is explained [here](http://www.thecodekey.com/Articles/ASP_net/Bind_Grid_with_Dataset.aspx).

In case you have debugged the code, and this suggestion is not working, please debug and post whether the data that is bound to the control.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: looks like you're not firing the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) event when you change the ItemsSource in ShowContacts.

Long answer: you should really look into MVVM. You should just create a ViewModel that maintains a list of ContactData, and bind to that list in your XAML (also databind your Contact dialog to a ContactData object):

```
var contact = new ContactData();
var cc = new CreateContact { Datacontext = contact };
cc.ShowDialog();

// ok button has been hit at this point,
// you can check for cancel if you want
(List<ContactData>)(dgContacts.ItemsSource).Add(contact);

// may still need to fire PropertyChanged here depending on binding
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is all the xaml and classes i use in the program. I really hope someone can help tell, what is wrong and why it wont show any data in the datagrid.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="KontaktInfo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dgContacts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="225" Width="517"/>

    <Button x:Name="cmdCreateContact" Content="Opret Kontakt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Click="cmdCreateContact_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="cmdDeleteContact" Content="Slet Kontakt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace KontaktInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string name;
        public string age;
        public string birthDate;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        private void cmdCreateContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateContact cc = new CreateContact();
            cc.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void ShowContacts()
        {
            try
            {
                dgContacts.ItemsSource = LoadContactData();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + e);
            }
        }

        private List<ContactData> LoadContactData()
        {
            List<ContactData> list = new List<ContactData>();
            list.Add(new ContactData()
            {
                Name = name,
                Age = age,
                BirthDate = birthDate
            });

            return list;
        }

    }

public class ContactData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CreateContact.xaml:

```
     <Window x:Class="KontaktInfo.CreateContact"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="CreateContact" Height="403" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Navn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272"/>
        <Label Content="Alder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272"/>
        <Label Content="Fødselsdag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="cmdOk" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,341,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="cmdOk_Click"/>
        <Button Name="cmdCancel" Content="Annuller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,341,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <DatePicker Name="dpBirthdate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CreateContact.cs:

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace KontaktInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CreateContact.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CreateContact : Window
    {
        public CreateContact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
            m.name = txtName.Text;
            m.age = txtAge.Text;
            m.birthDate = dpBirthdate.Text;
            m.ShowContacts();



        }
    }
}
```